# how to get all author and all custom field of wordpress with xmlrpc-c#

Tags: c#, wordpress, xml-rpc

I want to get all author and all customfield of wordpress with xmlrpc and add in comobox;
I do it with this code,

I use [JoeBlogsV1](http://joeblogs.codeplex.com/) Library

```
WordPressWrapper w = new WordPressWrapper(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, textBox3.Text);

var author = w.GetAuthors();
for (int i = 0; i < author.Count; i++)
{
   comboBox1.Items.Add(author[i].ToString());
}
```

but this return the `AlexJamesBrown.JoeBlogs.Structs.Author`
how to i can do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each author is in fact a `struct` with several fields:

```
public string user_id;
public string user_email;
public string user_login;
public string display_name;
```

You can access the fields individually:

```
for (int i = 0; i < author.Count; i++)
{
   comboBox1.Items.Add(author[i].display_name);
}
```

Comment: tanQ .here is i can get all User_id , user_login , Displaye name , but i cant`s see user_email !!? why ? another question is how to get all custom field ? and how to i can access meta_key field to get premission of user ?

Comment: @AliRezaGh hmmm... I could help on the c# front, but I don't know the library well enough to help you with the Wordpress stuff, sorry :)

Comment: thats ok , how to i can with c# ? i want to load all custom filed and user_email, another question is how to i can send post with tag ? and how to i can load all category ?

Comment: none of those are C# questions, it's all Wordpress API or the JoeBlogs library, none of which I'm really familiar with, sorry :(